# How can I keep my variable all the time without global variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

I have two GridViews. I've got method `GetGeneralDiagnosis` which returns a list of all diagnosis:

CODE    DIAGNOSIS
F50 Eating disorders
F51 Nonorganic sleep disorders

and method `GetSpecificDiagnosis` which returns more specific list:

CODE    DIAGNOSIS
F50.0   Anorexia nervosa
F50.1   Atypical anorexia nervosa
F51.0   Nonorganic insomnia
F51.1   Nonorganic hypersomnia

Now I've got method which bind SPECIFIC DIAGNOSIS to second GridView according to GENERAL DIAGNOSIS from first GridView.

```
protected void gvGeneralDiagnosis_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string generalDiagnosis = gvGeneralDiagnosis.DataKeys[gvGeneralDiagnosis.SelectedIndex].Values["ICD10Code"].ToString(); 
    var ICD10 = Visit.GetSpecificDiagnosis();   // here I'm getting data from database
    gvSpecificDiagnosis.DataSource = ICD10.Where(i => i.ICD10Code.Contains(generalDiagnosis)).Select(i => new { i.ICD10Name, i.ICD10Code });
    gvSpecificDiagnosis.DataBind();
}
```

I don't want to connect to database each time selected index is changed.

How can i get my list `var ICD10 = Visit.GetSpecificDiagnosis()` only once? I heard that global variables are very bad idea, so how can I do that in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a private member variable. This one "lives" as long as the class containing it lives. Wrap it with a property to access it and automatically read it from the database, if necessary.

```
private TypeOfICD10 _icd10;
private TypeOfICD10 ICD10
{
    get
    {
        if (_icd10 == null) { // Get from database.
            _icd10 = Visit.GetSpecificDiagnosis();   
        }
        return _icd10;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this and it will be read from the db only at the first call

```
protected void gvGeneralDiagnosis_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string generalDiagnosis = gvGeneralDiagnosis.DataKeys[gvGeneralDiagnosis.SelectedIndex].Values["ICD10Name"].ToString();
    gvSpecificDiagnosis.DataSource = ICD10
        .Where(i => i.ICD10Code.Contains(generalDiagnosis))
        .Select(i => new { i.ICD10Name, i.ICD10Code });
    gvSpecificDiagnosis.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why haven't I thought about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have your `Visit` class cache the returned data.

When `GetSpecificDiagnosis` is called, it will check whether this data was already retrieved from the database, and return it if it was. If it wasn't, it'll retrieve it from the database and save it to its cache.

One thing you should pay attention to is whether this data is static (i.e. never changes throughout the application's lifetime) or is it dynamic. In the first case, you won't have to do any special handling, but if it's the latter, you'll have to invalidate the cache one the information in the database has changed.

I recommend you to [have a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) to see how to get started with caching in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Visist class from your question but why not cache ICD10 this way you will be using the cached object and the Database call will made only if the Cache Key ICD10 has a value of null

**Example :**

```
if(Cache["ICD10"] == null)
{
 var ICD10 = Visit.GetSpecificDiagnosis();
 Cache["ICD10"] = ICD10;
}
else
{
var ICD10 =  Cache["ICD10"];
}
```

Comment: OK, but when I used `var ICD10 =  Cache["ICD10"]`, I can't see methods in Intellisense like Select, Where etc. I tried to write `(ICD10 as List<Visit>).Where(....)` but then my variable ICD10 is null.

Comment: Cache["ICD10"] = Visit.GetSpecificDiagnosis(); and when you get it out of the cast it back to its original type